# Material UI Floater button action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material UI's floater button, and I want it to open a menu onClick like its supposed to. It sucks that they havent shown a single example code where it actually opens up a menu and im kinnda struggling with it. I guess the way to go will be to use an onClick function but how I make a menu pop like it's supposed to the Google way? Any ideas?

```
   <Button
      variant="fab"
      color="secondary"
      aria-label="Add"
      style={style.floater}
      onClick={this.floatOptions}
    >
      <AddIcon />
    </Button>
```

Comment: `Button` isn't supposed to open a menu by default, it's just a fixed position button. Where is your `Menu`/`MenuItem` code that is triggered by the button click? At least try implementing the [simple menu](https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/#simple-menu) example There is also a [Speed Dial](https://material-ui.com/lab/speed-dial/) lab component that may suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry I didnt put the Menu code on as I thought it wouldnt be hardcoded. In a way that Ill have to set all the properties and JSS specifically for the button position right? and Speed Dial seems perfect! Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Alexander, I switched to the Speed Dial from Material UI Labs and was able to achieve exactly what I wanted! Thanks to him.